# filter latest comment using sql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to get latest comment result in same user id with query result in laravel controller. in this query i want to show only latest query if have multiple comment in same user id.

```
 $comments = DB::table('comments')
                    ->where('status', '=', 'Approved')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

this is my comments model method

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'avatar', 'user_id', 'comment', 'contact', 'status'];
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean just latest comment of each `user_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Comment::where('status', 'Approved')->latest()->get()->unique('user_id');
```

Comment: how can i get count in this query

Comment: comment count or user count?

Comment: i want to get comment count

Comment: use: Comment::where('status', 'Approved')->latest()->get()->unique('user_id')->count();